# Hilbert Modular Surface: Eigenfunctions of The Laplacian

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, eigenvalues, laplacian

The spectrum of the Laplacian on $L^2$ of a Hilbert modular surface decomposes into a discrete part and a continuous part $[1/4,\infty)$. The continuous part contains eigenvalues $\geq 1/4$.

I would like to know if the eigenfunctions of such eigenvalues lie also in $L^p$ for some $p>2$. If so, why?

Comment: For dimension one the answer is yes, as all those eigenfunctions are cusp forms which decay exponentially at the cusps. I think a similar argument should settle the case of Hilbert forms as well.